# передача данных из excel в word

Tags: excel, ms-word

в таблице эксель есть стобцы Имя, Фамилия, Отчество, Дата рожд., и т.д. Мне нужно отправить строку из таблицы в шаблон Word, как реализовать?

Comment: Используйте закладки в Word. Нет ни примера, ни кода. В таком варианте - на фриланс-площадку.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Слияния с использованием таблиц MS Excel (https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/Слияние-с-использованием-таблицы-excel-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3)